# Show/Hide div when click on radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen similar questions like this before but their example is using IDs. What if I want to use classes only?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgAgu/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $(".desc").hide(200);
        $(".desc" + test).show(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need a way to evaluate each element differently. Which is why ID is generally used. The HTML5 `data-` attribute is very nice as well, but with classes only your code sample manipulation is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you want to use only classes instead of IDs. You have to use unique class names for each HTML tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
    var selectedClass = $(this).attr("class");
    //alert(".dec" + selectedClass);
    $("div.desc").hide();

    $(".desc." + selectedClass).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myRadioGroup">

  2 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2" class="2cars" />3 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" class="3cars" />

  <div class="desc 2cars">
    2 Cars Selected
  </div>
  <div class="desc 3cars" style="display: none;">
    3 Cars
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to remove the `id` attributes for identifying the `div` elements, you could use `data()` attributes instead. Try this:

```
<div class="desc" data-cars="2">2 Cars Selected</div>
<div class="desc" data-cars="3" style="display: none;">3 Cars</div>
```

```js
$("div.desc").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('cars') == test;
}).show();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VgAgu/2433/)